# How to call affected_rows method from ci4 model

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have a model that extends CI4 builtin Model..

```
use CodeIgniter\Model;
use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time;

class ArticleModel extends Model { .. }
```

Any idea how do i perform the following?

```
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

thinking of getting it after deleting a row, most of the example using custom model, not extending ci4 model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be sure to set your database connection up correctly in `app/Config/App.php` or in your .env file.
Then `$this->db` from the core Model in CI4 doesn't create the connection. You have to create it first then you can perform queries.

`affected_rows()` method doesn't exist in CI4, it's now called `affectedRows()`. So to call it you will enventually come up with something like this :

```
    // your db connection
    $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
    // your query
    $this->db->query('MY QUERY');
    // number of affected rows
    $affected_rows = $this->db->affectedRows();
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition from above answer, to do it probably by getting the builder from CI4 model, since the model already has a db connection.

for example:

```
$model = new ArticleModel();
$builder = $model->builder();
$builder->db->affectedRows(); // this return
```